# Using values in an PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array split in half, but now i want to use the values in the array. 
The array is split like this

```
$teams = array_chunk($lista, count($lista)/2);
```

**Output**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 3 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 4 ) )
```

the numbers represent user id's.

How can i use these numbers?
Let's say that i want to select all id's in the first array (The idea is for these two arrays to act like teams) and then assign these values to a team column in my database.

**Let me explain a bit more**

I want the id's in the array to be assigned to a team. 
In array one the team will be, uhm. Blue! and in the other array the team will be red.
I will be using these randomised arrays to update my database table which contains a column called "team".

**Basically my question is how i can use these arrays to assign the specific id's in each array to a team. example, Can i select everything in array one and update all those values to team blue?**

For this question i'm sorry because i really don't know what i should include to make this question answerable, it might already be! but i'm not sure, so i if i have missed something just comment and i will clarify.

---

**Update**
This is what my database table looks like
https://gyazo.com/ed3c681575b26f31b77246436b43439a

As you can see, i have a column called "team", i want to update this to something depending on what team the user got selected into using the array splitter.
Everyone in Array one will have this updated to "team blue", and team red for array2.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your problem is. Is accessing the teams by `$teams[0]` and `$teams[1]` and then iterating over these subarrays not possible/what you want?

Comment: This would be a bit clearer if you explained your database schema, but it sounds like you're trying to add a set of IDs to a single database column. Instead, you should have a separate table that reflects the members of a team, e.g. `players(id, name, team_id)`, so that each entity is in its own row. Storing lists in a single column is not a good approach.

Comment: clarified a little see update ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [For Loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) to construct a query that does this for you.

An array inside of an array is called a [Multidimensional Array](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp).

You can access the elements of an array inside an array by just simply indexing twice:

```
$array = [ [1,2], [3,4] ];

echo $array[0][0]; // echo's 1
```

So you could loop over the first array for each team and loop into the second array to get each user id:

```
$array = [ [1,2], [3,4] ];

foreach($array as $team_id => $player_ids){
    foreach($player_ids as $player_id){
        echo "Player $player_id is in team $team_id";
    }
}
```

This example uses a [Foreach Loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

In this for loop you can construct a query that updates the rows for the players in the database.

If you are new to arrays in PHP I suggest you read this article: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Sure sounds interesting, but let's say that i have 15id's in each array, how does it work then? I can't have a static amount of id's since i dont know how many people will play the game each time. "$array = [ [1,2], [3,4] ];" This results in 4 players showing, if i have more players it wont work. How can i tackle this problem? :)

Comment: Please read the articles I linked in the answer. A for loop will go over each element in the specified array. If you are new to arrays start with the last one and then read more about for loops and multidimensional arrays. I will supply another article about foreach loops in the answer. @Jonas